# Content of database not showing up in Django

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I have some problems to get the content out of the django database.
I'm a bloody beginner at django so I did some tutorials. They've worked fine. Now I want to reproduce them in my own project with own variables so I can see if I've understood all the stuff.

So to come to my problem I initalized my modules in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Aboutme(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
```

This works because I could add content to the database.
So there is no mistake.

Now in the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from portfolio.models import Aboutme

def portfolio_index(request):
    
    aboutme = Aboutme.objects.all()
    context = {'aboutme': aboutme}

    return render(request, 'portfolio_index.html', context)
```

So finally in my HTML file, called portfolio_index.html, I call the content via

```
 <h1>{{ aboutme.author }}</h1>
```

I guess it's right. But the content of author doesn't showup, so what did I miss?
I can call static files via django, so couldn't be something wrong with django...

Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Aboutme.objects.all()` will give you a list of queryset so you need to loop through that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use a for loop to show "aboutme" because with "aboutme = Aboutme.objects.all()" you query a list of elements.

```
{% for aboutme_item in aboutme %}
    <h1>{{ aboutme_item.author }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, now it works. I used the for loop after I wrote this comment, but I've messed it up... Now with your answer it works fine!